# android- to maintain the changes made in the layout between the activities

Tags: android, layout, button

Suppose I changed the text of button using setText and moved to another activity. Then if I moved to previous activity,how can i maintain all these changes made in the layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you return to the previous activity.

In case you call `finish()` to the current one, the `onCreate()` of the previous activity does not get called. Thus, in case you have made a change some time, when going back the `setContentView()` will not get called, thus the layout will be exactly as it was. (except you perform a different action in the `onResume()`)

In case you call `startActivity()` to return back, it depends on the flags of the intent.

In any case, unless an activity is not destroyed (and you do not change it in any way), it maintains its current layout.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But i am using intent to launch the new activity. what changes have to be made in intent flags?